# Symfony 3.4 Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::$flush

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I'm trying to create a service with little success.

```
class NotificationService {

public $manager;

public function __construct($manager) {

    $this->manager = $manager;
}

public function set($user, $type, $typeId, $extra = null){

    $em = $this->manager;

    $notification = new Notification();
    $notification->setUser($user);
    $notification->setType($type);
    $notification->setTypeId($typeId);
    $notification->setReaded(0);
    $notification->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
    $notification->setExtra($extra);

    $em->persist($notification);
    $flush = $em->flush;

    if($flush == null){
        $status = true;
    }else{
        $status = false;
    }

    return $status;
}
```

}

And here's my services.yml:

```
app.notification_service:
    class: AppBundle\Services\NotificationService
    public: true
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

I'm calling the service in the LikeController. The idea is to notify a member when someone likes their post:

```
public function likeAction(Request $request){
    $user = $this->getUser();
    $id = $request->get('id');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $publication = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:Publication')->find($id);

    $like = new Like();
    $like->setUser($user);
    $like->setPublication($publication);

    $em->persist($like);
    $flush = $em->flush();

    if($flush == NULL){
        $notification = $this->get('app.notification_service');
        $notification->set($publication->getUser(), 'like', $user->getId(), $publication->getId());

        $status = 'You like this post';
    }else{
        $status = 'Could not save the like.';
    }

    return new JsonResponse(['status' => $status]);
}
```

This doesn't work when I test it. Instead, I get an exception, the EntityManager is not recognizing the flush method:

Undefined property: Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::$flush

Could someone tell me how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: $em->flush();  The parens are important.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for 4 hours. I feel like an idiot! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You must write this:

`$flush = $em->flush();`

instead:

`$flush = $em->flush;`